# Mod_rewrite and redirect old page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using rewriting in my .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php [L]
```

It works, that's cool (when I put `www.something.com/blog`, it get `blog.php` content), but I would love to avoid possible duplicates of my web.

So I want to redirect `www.something.com/blog.php` only to `www.something.com/blog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this new rule on top:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(blog)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, but all it do now, is that version without .php works, with .php does not.

Comment: Still redirects old blog.php to something like this: www.something.com/data/web/virtuals/55462/virtual/www/blog :(